# why this is legal for c without l-value when accessing a register in STM32

Tags: c, stm32, cpu-registers

```
for(i=0; i<headerLength; i++)
{
    SPIx->DR = headerBuffer[i];

    while ((SPIx->SR & SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == (uint16_t)RESET);

    SPIx->DR ;
}
```

the statement SPIx->DR ;  is used for clearing the 'Data Register' of stm32's SPI peripheral when reading it.

why it's legal without having an l-value?
shouldn't it be something like temp = SPIx->DR; ?

paul

Answer (score 3):

> why it's legal without having an l-value?

An lvalue is only relevant in the context of an assignment. An expression can be written without an lvalue anywhere in sight, like:

```
printf("hello\n");
```

or

```
x++;
```

or

```
SPIx->DR;
```

All of these statements are valid expressions, and can be used as rvalues. (Recall that `printf` returns a value.) The only thing that's different about the last one is that it wouldn't have any side effects but for the `volatile` declaration of `SPIx`.